# What species of insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I saw this insect near a beach in Corsica France:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a **mole cricket** (in the family *Gryllotalpidae*).

[image: Mole-cricket wiki]

Notice the cricket-like appearance of the posterior/abdominal portion of the insect, but the powerful, broad and flattened fore-legs that are designed for digging (reminiscent of a mole's digging legs). In fact, the family name literally means cricket-mole (from Latin, '*gryllus*' = cricket and '*talpa*' = mole).

Mole-cricket fore-legs:

[image: prairie mole cricket foreleg]

[image: northern mole cricket foreleg]

Anterior mole legs:

[image: Mole legs]

The *Gryllotalpidae* are a [monophyletic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophyly) group in the order [Orthoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptera) (grasshoppers, locusts and crickets). A 2015 [paper](http://biotaxa.org/Zootaxa/article/view/zootaxa.3985.4.1) by O. J. Cadena-Castañeda clarified/updated the phylogeny of this family using morphological characteristics.

The specific species is dependent on your location and morphological characteristics (and possiblly ["song"](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.1665/1082-6467%282006%2915%5B53%3AMACSCI%5D2.0.CO%3B2?journalCode=orth) [differences](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-3113.1970.tb00265.x/abstract?) too). 
See [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/walker/buzz/s341a.htm) for a brief explanation and access to dichotomous keys to use to better ID the specific genus. Other keys exist [here (SE USA)](http://mississippientomologicalmuseum.org.msstate.edu/Researchtaxapages/Orthoptera/Gryllotalpidae/keys/Gryllotalpidae_Genera_Key.html), [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27395653), and likely via a google search. However, I couldn't quickly find a European key.

[Here's](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/turf/pest_mole_crickets.htm) an additional useful resource on these insects from University of Florida Entomology and Nematology Department.

Based on the OP's location in France, the **European mole-cricket *Gryllotalpa gryllotalpa*** (or one of it's closely related European allies in the *Gryllotalpa* genus) is probably a good initial guess at the OP's specific species. As seen from UC Berkeley's ["CalPhotos"](http://calphotos.berkeley.edu/) collection:

[image: European mole cricket]

Comment: Note: to follow-up with a now deleted answer. The OP's insect is NOT an earwig. The confusion lies in the existence of posterior [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus). Though cerci are well known on earwigs (i.e., their "pincers"), many insects have a pair of posterior cerci (though typically they are functionless vestigial structures). Therefore, cerci are not strictly indicative of earwigs. Further, the enlarged and flattened fore-limbs of the OP's picture are not present in any species of earwig (which do not dig), but instead are the calling-card for the digging mole-crickets

Comment: I assumed the deleted answer (earwig) was incorrect and that's why I waited for more answers. Thanks for the detailed explanation!